# Is there any software which can scrape review queues?

Tags: discussion, review, screen-scraping

Is there any software one can use to scrape Stack Exchange review queues of choice and e.g. print a summary to standard output?

A possible input document:

```
- stackoverflow.com
  - triage
  - first posts
  - late answers
- serverfault.com
  - first posts
- superuser.com
  - first posts
  - late answers
- unicorns.stackexchange.com  # whatever
  - first posts
```

A possible standard output:

```
stackoverflow.com
 triage                     3402
 first posts                 324
 late answers                 30
serverfault.com
 first posts                  12
superuser.com
 first posts                 683
 late answers                130
unicorns.stackexchange.com
 first posts               ERROR
```

Comment: I have a scraper (in Perl). Perhaps we can trade?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 9):

For *historical* data, one can use a SEDE query like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1044466/number-of-review-tasks-per-day) - it shows the number of review tasks which were created on a certain day, split by type.

You can use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits) to get a (real-time) list of pending suggested edits to posts, which form the majority of the Suggested Edits review queue (the only items which are missing are suggested edits to tag wikis and excerpts).

You'd have to write a scraper for the review page yourself, there's no standard software for this. There are userscripts, [Review Stalker](https://stackapps.com/q/4086/34061) and [Review Stalker Reloaded](https://stackapps.com/q/6869/34061) which already did/do this, maybe you can draw some inspiration from them?